# Property 'apply' is missing in type 'DotenvWebpackPlugin' but required in type 'Plugin'

Tags: typescript, webpack

Property 'apply' is missing in type 'DotenvWebpackPlugin' but required in type 'Plugin'.[image]

Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a type definition issue with the DotenvWebpackPlugin types, although looking at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/dotenv-webpack it looks like the `apply` property is there; make sure you're using the latest version of `@types/dotenv-webpack`

Alternatively, since this error doesn't seem like it causes a runtime error, you can ignore it with a `// @ts-ignore` comment above that line.